# Validate array of form fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms

I'm trying to setup some jQuery to validate an array of fields for a form. I feel like I'm on the right track but the setup doesn't work as I want it to. Currently, if any of the fields in the array have been filled in, the else statement is triggered. But I want to make sure ALL fields in the array are filled in. I'm wondering if I need to create a boolean variable?

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var SubmitBtn = $('#Schedule-Button');
        var SchFirstName = $('#FName');
        var SchLastName = $('#LName');
        var SchAddress = $('#Address');
        var SchCity = $('#City');
        var SchZip = $('#Zip');
        var SchEmail = $('#Email');
        var SchPhone = $('#Phone');
        var SchService = $('#ServiceReq');
        var ApptForm = $('#appt-form');
        var errors = false;
        var SchedulePopup = $('[data-remodal-id=sch-modal]').remodal();

        SubmitBtn.on('click', function(e){
            var required = [SchFirstName, SchLastName, SchAddress, SchCity,  SchZip, SchEmail, SchPhone, SchService];
            e.preventDefault();
            for(i=0;i<required.length;i++){
                var input = required[i];
                if((input.val()== "")){
                    input.addClass('error-field');
                    $('.Sch-Error-Msg').show();
                }
                else{
                    SchedulePopup.close();
                    input.removeClass('error-field');
                    $('.Sch-Error-Msg').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I don't think you want to close the popup on the else. You want to close it if all fields are correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var SubmitBtn = $('#Schedule-Button');
        var SchFirstName = $('#FName');
        var SchLastName = $('#LName');
        var SchAddress = $('#Address');
        var SchCity = $('#City');
        var SchZip = $('#Zip');
        var SchEmail = $('#Email');
        var SchPhone = $('#Phone');
        var SchService = $('#ServiceReq');
        var ApptForm = $('#appt-form');
        var errors = false;
        var SchedulePopup = $('[data-remodal-id=sch-modal]').remodal();

        SubmitBtn.on('click', function(e){
            var required = [SchFirstName, SchLastName, SchAddress, SchCity,  SchZip, SchEmail, SchPhone, SchService],
                containsError = false;
            e.preventDefault();

            for(i=0;i<required.length;i++){
                var input = required[i];
                if((input.val()== "")){
                    containsError = true;
                    input.addClass('error-field');
                    $('.Sch-Error-Msg').show();
                }
                else{
                    input.removeClass('error-field');
                    $('.Sch-Error-Msg').hide();
                }
            }
            if (containsError) {
                SchedulePopup.close();
            }
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks!